# VBA IE change dropdown value

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

Tried the below code for following URL [Scripture look up](http://ebible.org/study/). Please how to change drop down value from `WEB` to `RV1909`?

```vb
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = IEApp.document

TestV2 = ""
TestV3 = ""

TestV2 = Doc.getElementsByClassName("app-list text-list")(0).innerText
Debug.Print "4b of 5: " & TestV2    

IEApp.Doc.getElementsByClassName("app-list text-list").selectedIndex = 1
IEApp.Doc.getElementsByClassName("app-list text-list").FireEvent ("onchange")

TestV3 = Doc.getElementsByClassName("app-list text-list")(0).innerText
Debug.Print "4c of 5: " & TestV3
```

Tried many approaches from other posts, the following does not work:

```vb
IEApp.Doc.getElementsByClassName("app-list text-list")(0).innerHTML = "RV1909"
```

Here is the screenshot of Chrome Inspector:

[image: Screenshot of Chrome Inspector]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's not enough just change `div.app-list.text-list` element `innerText`, as you can see that element is simple `div`, but not even `ul`. It should be changed by scripts which are called on `click` events. So, first of all you need to click on `div` to display the entire list, and then click on the RV1909 item. The below example shows how that could be done:

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim oIE As Object
    Dim oDiv As Object

    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With oIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://ebible.org/study/"
        Do While .readyState <> 4 Or .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
        With .Document
            Do While .readyState <> "complete"
                DoEvents
            Loop
            Set oDiv = .getElementsByClassName("app-list text-list")(0)
            oDiv.Click
            Do While .readyState <> "complete"
                DoEvents
            Loop
            For Each oNode In .getElementsByClassName("text-chooser-main")(0).getElementsByClassName("text-chooser-abbr")
                If oNode.innerText = "RV1909" Then
                    oNode.Click
                    Do While oDiv.innerText <> "RV1909"
                        DoEvents
                    Loop
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change the html div element `<div class=app-list text-list>WEB</div>` to `<div class=app-list text-list>RV1909</div>`

Comment: Please, how would I modify this to change the DIV

IEApp.Doc.getElementsByClassName("app-list text-list")(0).Value = "RV1909"

Comment: Tried many approaches from other posts, the following does not work:
IEApp.Doc.getElementsByClassName("app-list text-list")(0).innerHTML = "RV1909"